# J-query J-player is not auto playing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have used jPlayer in my music site .The actual songs data in dynamic.It is been adding on user checks from 10 listed songs on every page.jPlayer is getting added with the playlist but not autoplaying.when i'm clicking manually only it is getting palyed.
I tried with playItem= 0,playItem= 1,playItem= 2...etc.,

Can any body suggest be about this issue .How to add dynamic playlist and set it play automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out:

[Stack Overflow: How to disable jQuery.jplayer autoplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692430/how-to-disable-jquery-jplayer-autoplay)

Else try consulting the 
[jPlayer 1.2.0 Developer Guide](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/developer-guide.htm)