# How to disable jQuery.jplayer autoplay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jplayer

when i initialize the player like this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            this.element.jPlayer("setFile", "/previews/cancion.mp3", "/previews/horse.ogg").jPlayer("play");
        },
        volume: 50,
        oggSupport: true
    })
```

is there any way to disable the autoplay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `.jPlayer("play")`

Comment: And what about disabling looping?

Comment: I don't believe it does that by default... or does it?

Answer (score 1):

how about reading the manual:

http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/developer-guide.htm

to disable looping (repeat) i would try:

```
$("#jpId").jPlayer("onSoundComplete", function() {
  // Directly access this instance's jPlayer methods. (Does not support chaining.)
  this.stop(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.jPlayer("pause");
```

That's it. It worked for my project. Put that at the end of the function that plays the song. Not the function that loads the jplayer, but the track selecting function.

Cheers to those looking at this 6-7 years later. :)  The others did help me come to this simple conclusive solution.